# Changing UIImageView transform scale broke movement system

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am trying to create an Image view which I can move and scale on screen. the problem is that when I change the scale of the Image, the movement system seams to be broken.

I wrote some code to drag the object from an anchor point which could be different from the center of the UIImage, but the scale ruined the process.

```
 /*
See LICENSE folder for this sample’s licensing information.

Abstract:
Main view controller for the AR experience.
*/

import ARKit
import SceneKit
import UIKit
import ModelIO

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSessionDelegate , UIGestureRecognizerDelegate{



// MARK: Outlets

@IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!

@IBOutlet weak var blurView: UIVisualEffectView!


@IBOutlet weak var dropdown: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var AddStickerButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var deleteStickerButton: UIImageView!
var offset : CGPoint = CGPoint.zero
var isDeleteVisible : Bool = false


let array:[String] = ["HappyHeart_Lisa", "Logo_bucato", "Sweety_2_Lisa", "Sweety_Lisa", "Tonglue_Lisa"]


lazy var statusViewController: StatusViewController = {
    return childViewControllers.lazy.flatMap({ $0 as? StatusViewController }).first!
}()

var stickers = [Sticker]()


// MARK: Properties

var myScene : SCNScene!
/// Convenience accessor for the session owned by ARSCNView.
var session: ARSession {
    sceneView.session.configuration
    //sceneView.scene.background.contents = UIColor.black

    return sceneView.session
}



var nodeForContentType = [VirtualContentType: VirtualFaceNode]()    //Tiene sotto controllo la selezione(Tipo maschera)

let contentUpdater = VirtualContentUpdater()                    //Chiama la VirtualContentUpdater.swift

var selectedVirtualContent: VirtualContentType = .faceGeometry {
    didSet {
        // Set the selected content based on the content type.
        contentUpdater.virtualFaceNode = nodeForContentType[selectedVirtualContent]
    }
}

// MARK: - View Controller Life Cycle

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    sceneView.delegate = contentUpdater
    sceneView.session.delegate = self
    sceneView.automaticallyUpdatesLighting = true

    createFaceGeometry()

    // Set the initial face content, if any.
    contentUpdater.virtualFaceNode = nodeForContentType[selectedVirtualContent]

    // Hook up status view controller callback(s).
    statusViewController.restartExperienceHandler = { [unowned self] in
        self.restartExperience()


    }

    let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(scale))
    let rotationGesture = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(rotate))
    pinchGesture.delegate = self
    rotationGesture.delegate = self
    view.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(rotationGesture)



}



override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    /*
        AR experiences typically involve moving the device without
        touch input for some time, so prevent auto screen dimming.
    */
    UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true

    resetTracking()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    session.pause()
}

// MARK: - Setup

/// - Tag: CreateARSCNFaceGeometry
func createFaceGeometry() {
    // This relies on the earlier check of `ARFaceTrackingConfiguration.isSupported`.
    let device = sceneView.device!
    let maskGeometry = ARSCNFaceGeometry(device: device)!
    let glassesGeometry = ARSCNFaceGeometry(device: device)!

    nodeForContentType = [
        .faceGeometry: Mask(geometry: maskGeometry),
        .overlayModel: GlassesOverlay(geometry: glassesGeometry),
        .blendShapeModel: RobotHead(),
        .sfere: RobotHead()
    ]
}

// MARK: - ARSessionDelegate

func session(_ session: ARSession, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    guard error is ARError else { return }

    let errorWithInfo = error as NSError
    let messages = [
        errorWithInfo.localizedDescription,
        errorWithInfo.localizedFailureReason,
        errorWithInfo.localizedRecoverySuggestion
    ]
    let errorMessage = messages.flatMap({ $0 }).joined(separator: "\n")

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.displayErrorMessage(title: "The AR session failed.", message: errorMessage)
    }
}

func sessionWasInterrupted(_ session: ARSession) {
    blurView.isHidden = false
    statusViewController.showMessage("""
    SESSION INTERRUPTED
    The session will be reset after the interruption has ended.
    """, autoHide: false)
}

func sessionInterruptionEnded(_ session: ARSession) {
    blurView.isHidden = true

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.resetTracking()
    }
}

/// - Tag: ARFaceTrackingSetup
func resetTracking() {
    statusViewController.showMessage("STARTING A NEW SESSION")

    guard ARFaceTrackingConfiguration.isSupported else { return }
    let configuration = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()
    configuration.isLightEstimationEnabled = true

    session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
}

// MARK: - Interface Actions

/// - Tag: restartExperience
func restartExperience() {
    // Disable Restart button for a while in order to give the session enough time to restart.
    statusViewController.isRestartExperienceButtonEnabled = false
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) {
        self.statusViewController.isRestartExperienceButtonEnabled = true
    }

    resetTracking()
}

// MARK: - Error handling

func displayErrorMessage(title: String, message: String) {
    // Blur the background.
    blurView.isHidden = false

    // Present an alert informing about the error that has occurred.
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let restartAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Restart Session", style: .default) { _ in
        alertController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.blurView.isHidden = true
        self.resetTracking()
    }
    alertController.addAction(restartAction)
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}



//Create a new Sticker


func createNewSticker(){
    stickers.append(Sticker(view : self.view, viewCtrl : self))

}


@IBAction func addNewSticker(_ sender: Any) {
    createNewSticker()
}

//Function To Move the Stickers, all the Touch Events Listener

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        var location = touch.location(in: self.view)
        for sticker in stickers {
            if(sticker.imageView.frame.contains(location) && !isSomeOneMoving()){
                //sticker.imageView.center = location

                offset = touch.location(in: sticker.imageView)

                let offsetPercentage = CGPoint(x: offset.x / sticker.imageView.bounds.width, y: offset.y / sticker.imageView.bounds.height)

                let offsetScaled = CGPoint(x: sticker.imageView.frame.width * offsetPercentage.x, y: sticker.imageView.frame.height * offsetPercentage.y)

                offset.x = (sticker.imageView.frame.width / 2) - offsetScaled.x

                offset.y = (sticker.imageView.frame.height / 2) - offsetScaled.y

                location = touch.location(in: self.view)
                location.x = (location.x + offset.x)
                location.y = (location.y + offset.y)

                sticker.imageView.center = location

                disableAllStickersMovements()
                isDeleteVisible = true
                sticker.isStickerMoving = true;
                deleteStickerButton.isHidden = false

            }
        }
    }
}

func disableAllStickersMovements(){
    for sticker in stickers {
        sticker.isStickerMoving = false;
    }
}

func isSomeOneMoving() -> Bool{
    for sticker in stickers {
        if(sticker.isStickerMoving){
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

var lastLocationTouched : CGPoint = CGPoint.zero
var lastStickerTouched : Sticker = Sticker()



override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        var location = touch.location(in: self.view)
        for sticker in stickers {
            if(sticker.imageView.frame.contains(location) && sticker.isStickerMoving){
                lastLocationTouched = location

                location = touch.location(in: self.view)
                location.x = (location.x + offset.x)
                location.y = (location.y + offset.y)

                sticker.imageView.center = location
                //sticker.imageView.center = location
            }
            if(deleteStickerButton.frame.contains(lastLocationTouched) && isDeleteVisible && sticker.isStickerMoving){
                sticker.imageView.alpha = CGFloat(0.5)
            }else{
                sticker.imageView.alpha = CGFloat(1)
            }
        }
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for sticker in stickers {

        if(deleteStickerButton.frame.contains(lastLocationTouched) && isDeleteVisible && sticker.isStickerMoving){
            removeASticker(sticker : sticker)
            disableAllStickersMovements()

        }
    }
    disableAllStickersMovements()

    isDeleteVisible = false
    deleteStickerButton.isHidden = true
}
func removeASticker(sticker : Sticker  ){
    sticker.imageView.removeFromSuperview()
    let stickerPosition = stickers.index(of: sticker)!
    stickers.remove(at: stickerPosition)
    for sticker in stickers {
        sticker.isStickerMoving = false;
    }
}

var identity = CGAffineTransform.identity


@objc func scale(_ gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    for sticker in stickers {
        if(sticker.isStickerMoving){
            switch gesture.state {
            case .began:
                identity = sticker.imageView.transform
            case .changed,.ended:
                sticker.imageView.transform = identity.scaledBy(x: gesture.scale, y: gesture.scale)
            case .cancelled:
                break
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }

}

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
@objc func rotate(_ gesture: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
    for sticker in stickers {
        if(sticker.isStickerMoving){
            sticker.imageView.transform = sticker.imageView.transform.rotated(by: gesture.rotation)
        }
    }
}
```

}

and then the sticker class

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class Sticker : NSObject, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate{



var location = CGPoint(x: 0 , y: 0);

var sticker_isMoving = false;

let imageView = UIImageView()

var isStickerMoving : Bool = false;

init(view : UIView, viewCtrl : ViewController ) {
    super.init()
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "BroccolFace_Lisa.png")
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit

    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: view.center.x, y: view.center.y, width: 200, height: 200)
    view.addSubview(imageView)


}

override init(){

}
```

}

Comment: Share the whole code so we can play around with it

Comment: U mean all the project, or only the 3 methods I wrote in the post

Comment: Is the problem that when scaled taping on the imageView snaps it to a new position before dragging begins?

Comment: the problem is that after an image has been scaled, the anchor point results alterated from the correct position, so the Image being moved out of screen, or just moved of a few pixels

Comment: That is because the `imageView.bounds` and the `touch.location(in: imageView)` return values that are not modified by the scaling you have done.

Comment: Is there any way to correct the returned value? like using the contentScaleFactor

Comment: I meant minimal code that I can test for myself

Comment: I will add an answer showing a simple approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `imageView.bounds` and the `touch.location(in: imageView)` are in unscaled values.  This will overcome the problem:

```
offset = touch.location(in: imageView)

let offsetPercentage = CGPoint(x: offset.x / imageView.bounds.width, y: offset.y / imageView.bounds.height)

let offsetScaled = CGPoint(x: imageView.frame.width * offsetPercentage.x, y: imageView.frame.height * offsetPercentage.y)

offset.x = (imageView.frame.width / 2) - offsetScaled.x

offset.y = (imageView.frame.height / 2) - offsetScaled.y
```

Basically it converts the offset into a percentage based on the unscaled values and then converts that into scaled values based on the imageView frame (which is modified by the scale).  It then uses that to calculate the offset.

**EDIT (NUMBER TWO)**

This is more complete way to do it and it should solve any issues that may arise due to scaling or rotation.

1. Add this structure to hold the details of the dragging for images:

   ```
   struct DragInfo {
       let imageView: UIImageView
       let startPoint: CGPoint
   }
   ```
2. Add these instance variables (you can also remove offset if you want):

   ```
   var dragStartPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint.zero
   var currentDragItems: [DragInfo] = []
   var dragTouch: UITouch?
   ```
3. Change touchesBegan to this:

   ```
   override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
       guard self.dragTouch == nil, let touch = touches.first else { return }

       self.dragTouch = touch

       let location = touch.location(in: self.view)

       self.dragStartPoint = location

       for imageView in self.imageList {
           if imageView.frame.contains(location) {
               self.currentDragItems.append(DragInfo(imageView: imageView, startPoint: imageView.center))
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Change touchesMoved to this:

   ```
   override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
       guard let dragTouch = self.dragTouch else { return }

       for touch in touches {
           if touch == dragTouch {
               let location = touch.location(in: self.view)
               let offset = CGPoint(x: location.x - self.dragStartPoint.x, y: location.y - self.dragStartPoint.y)
               for dragInfo in self.currentDragItems {
                   let imageOffSet = CGPoint(x: dragInfo.startPoint.x + offset.x, y: dragInfo.startPoint.y + offset.y)
                   dragInfo.imageView.center = imageOffSet
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
5. Change touchesEnded to this:

   ```
   override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
       guard let dragTouch = self.dragTouch, touches.contains(dragTouch) else { return }

       self.currentDragItems.removeAll()
       self.dragTouch = nil
   }
   ```
6. Set the following properties on the gesture recognisers used:

   ```
   scaleGesture.delaysTouchesEnded = false
   scaleGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false

   rotationGesture.delaysTouchesEnded = false
   rotationGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
   ```

Some explanation about how it works.

With all the touch events it only considers the first touch because dragging from multiple touches doesn't make much sense (what if two touches were over the same image view and move differently).  It records this touch and then only considers that touch for dragging things around.

When touchesBegan is called it checks no touch for dragging exists (indicating a drag in progress) and it finds all image views that are under the touch and for each one it records the details of itself and it start centre position in a DragInfo structure and stores it in the currentDragItems array.  It also records the position the touch started in the main view and the touch that initiated it.

When touchesMoved is called it only considers the touch that started the dragging and it calculates the offset from the original position the touch started in the main view and then goes down the list of images involved in the dragging and calculates their new centre based on their original starting position and the offset calculated and sets that as the new centre.

When touchesEnded is called assuming it is the dragging touch that is ended it clears the array of DragInfo objects to ready for the next drag.

You need to set the delaysTouchesEnded and cancelsTouchesInView properties on all gesture recognisers so that all touches are passed through to the view otherwise the touchesEnded methods in particular are not called.

Doing the calculations like this removes the problems of scale and rotation as you are just concerned with offsets from initial positions.  It also works if multiple image views are dragged at the same time as their details are kept separately.

Now there are some things to be aware of:

1. You will need to put in all the other code you app required as this is just a basic example to show the idea.
2. This assumes that you only want to drag image views that you pick up at the start.  If you want to collect image views as you drag around you would need to develop a much more complicated system.
3. As I stated only one drag operation can be in progress at a time and it takes the first touch registered as this source touch.  This source touch is then used to filter out any other touches that may happen.  This is done to keep things simple and otherwise you would have to account for all kinds of strange situations like if multiple touches were on the same image view.

I hope this all makes sense and you can adapt it to solve your problem.

Comment: Before of this issue I setted the offset only in the touchesBegan function, now I think this code should stay also in the touchesMoved... Is that correct ?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to achieve.  If you want to for example touch the corner and have that as the anchor for dragging it works fine as it is.

Comment: it is like anything changed... the issue is still there

Comment: Hmm, it works fine for me which means either my understanding of the problem is flawed (even though it should have had some affect), you made a mistake while implementing it (mistype, etc) or something else is affecting it.  Can you update the question to show what you have now or even better share the project (dropbox, git, etc).

Comment: I add all the important classes

Comment: I'm just updating my test project and will get back to you.

Comment: Ok it appears to work fine in that I can drag the images about unless I drag over the top of one of the other images.  Is that the issue you are getting?

Comment: Try to resize the image and then drag it on the screen. If u do this, the image will get a wrong anchor point

Comment: maybe it is a rotation issue ?

Comment: Yes rotation will cause a big issue.  Does it work without any rotation?

Comment: It works, but after i touch once time the object, infact the first hit, it doesn't  work, but then it is perfect, untill i rotate the object

Comment: Yep rotation is really going to be a problem.  I'm in the middle of some work at the moment.  I will have a think about it and see what I can come up with.

Comment: I adapt the code to my project, but it seams to disable both rotation and scale

Comment: You must have done something wrong in the implementation as nothing I put has anything to do with scaling or rotating.  Can you share the project (dropbox, git, etc) for me to take a look?

Comment: I am so stupid, the code was working properly,but I made an error with a boolean, which was stopping the whole execution. I will mark your post as correct answer

Comment: It's always the simple mistakes that I miss.  I end up spending hours looking for some complex bug and then find I have just misspelled something or something else simple like that.  Glad it's working now.

Comment: the only problem is that touching external to the image, make it move wrong, I will check if i can solve this issue allowing only a single tap

Comment: Mine is just a basic example you will probably need to modify it a bit to suit your requirements.  If you get stuck you may need to share more about your project usage to be able to determine the issue.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VbV4PqyzRTEUGYvUwcD1eCSkLLmuyTi8 this is the whole project link, take a look if u can.

Comment: Your scale and rotate gestures are causing problems with the dragging particularly as they use the same currentDragInfo array.  Also try to do dragging with multiple touches is going to be all but impossible.  I'm looking at a way around it and will get back to you.

Comment: I have changed my example to hopefully solve the problems you have encountered.  Again it is a test example so you will have to integrate it back into your code.  On a slightly unrelated note your app currently will be rejected by Apple for a couple of reasons (you may be aware of them).  1)  It requires usage of the TrueDepth front-facing camera on an iPhone X and you are must provide alternate functionality if that is not available. 2) It doesn't adapt it's layout to run on an iPad when simulating an iPhone (design as an iPhone 4).

Comment: It take a single imageView... and then  the app stucks. I will check the code towmorrow. Thx for all the helping

Comment: Ok if you have trouble getting it working share the updated project.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extension that I use to pan, pinch and rotate an image with `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` and `UIRotationGestureRecognizer`

```
extension ViewController : UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func panGesture(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch gesture.state {
    case .ended: fallthrough
    case .changed:
        let translation = gesture.translation(in: gesture.view)

        if let view = gesture.view {
            var finalPoint = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x, y:view.center.y + translation.y)

            finalPoint.x = min(max(finalPoint.x, 0), self.myImageView.bounds.size.width)
            finalPoint.y = min(max(finalPoint.y, 0), self.myImageView.bounds.size.height)

            view.center = finalPoint

            gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: gesture.view)
        }

    default : break
    }
}

func pinchGesture(gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    switch gesture.state {
    case .changed:
        let scale = gesture.scale
        gesture.view?.transform = gesture.view!.transform.scaledBy(x: scale, y: scale)
        gesture.scale = 1
    default : break
    }
}

func rotateGesture(gesture: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
    switch gesture.state {
    case .changed:
        let rotation = gesture.rotation
        gesture.view?.transform = gesture.view!.transform.rotated(by: rotation)
        gesture.rotation = 0
    default : break
    }
}
}
```

setting the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` will help you do the three of gestures at the same time.

Comment: While useful that's not going to solve the original question.